# Can't pass value down promise chain

Tags: promise, bluebird

In my code I have...

```
p.then(() => { console.log('Then 1'); return 'Hi Mum!!'});
```

... and

```
p.then(function(val) { console.log('Then 2: ' + val);
```

Output when promise is resolved...

> Then 1
>   Then 2: undefined

How do I access the return from Then 1 in Then 2?

Comment: You need to invoke the second `.then()` on the return value of the first `.then()` call, not on `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a *chain*, you're registering the second continuation on the initial promise instead of the promise returned from the previous `then` call. It should look like this:

```
p.then(() => { console.log('Then 1'); return 'Hi Mum!!'})
 .then(function(val) { console.log('Then 2: ' + val) });
```

Another way to do this is to assign the first *chain* to a variable and provide `then` call to it:

```
const chain = p.then(() => { console.log('Then 1'); return 'Hi Mum!!'})
// ...
chain.then(function(val) { console.log('Then 2: ' + val); });
```

This allows you to pass the promise chain around and still have the expected values being passed.

Comment: I've passed a function to the 'Hi Mum' component so that after it's updated the promise, it can pass the result back.